# Update the count value in Column Item Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-mvvm, jetpack-compose-column

Product Item Composable :

```
    @Composable
fun ProductItem(product: Product, index: Int) {

    val addProductViewModel = hiltViewModel<AddProductVM>()

    val productSelectedIndex = remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()) {

            Column() {

                Row{
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .weight(1f)
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                    ) {
                        if (product.variants[0].cart_count > 0) {
                            Row {
                                Text(text = product.variants[0].cart_count.toString())
                      }
                        } else {
                            Text(
                                text = "Add To Cart", // "Add To Cart" text
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .clickable {
                                        productSelectedIndex.intValue = index
                                        val newCount = product.variants[0].cart_count + 1
                                        addProductViewModel.addProduct(product.variants[0].product_id.toString(),
                                            newCount.toString(),
                                            product.variants[0].id.toString())
                                    }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I want to update the text count value by clicking Add to Cart text

AddProductResult Composable :

```
    @Composable
fun AddProductResult(addProductResult: ApiResult<AddProduct>) {

    when (addProductResult) {
        is ApiResult.Loading -> {
            // Loading state code for products
        }

        is ApiResult.Error -> {
            Log.e("addproductapicall", "failure error: " + addProductResult.error.toString())
        }

        is ApiResult.Success -> {
            val Result = addProductResult.data?.error
            if(Result == true) {
                Log.e("addproductapicall", "success success: " + addProductResult.data.message.toString())
            } else {
                Log.e("addproductapicall", "failure success: " + addProductResult.data?.message.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to update the UI of clicked Product count text when I clicked on "Add To Cart" text only after getting response from AddProductResult when Result == false

now. its updating before api call result

This is my view model

AddProductVM :

```
    @HiltViewModel
class AddProductVM @Inject constructor(private val apiService: ApiService,
                                       private val defaultDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
): ViewModel() {

    private val _addProductList= MutableStateFlow<ApiResult<AddProduct>>(ApiResult.Empty())
    val addProductList= _addProductList.asStateFlow()

    fun addProduct(productId:String,qty:String,productVariantId:String){
        _addProductList.value = ApiResult.Loading()
        viewModelScope.launch {
            apiService.addProduct(productId,qty,productVariantId)
                .flowOn(defaultDispatcher)
                .catch {
                    _addProductList.value= ApiResult.Error(it.message ?: "Something went wrong")
                }
                .collect{
                    _addProductList.value=it
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, why didn't you add the code of addProductViewModel.addProduct function?

Comment: yes , I have added now, please check @Faruk Karaca

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your ApiResult class should look like this.
You should check the Success and Error states separately.
You don't' need to check errors again in `ApiResult.Success`.

```
sealed class ApiResult<out T> {
    object Loading: ApiResult<Nothing>()

    data class Success<out T>(
        val data: T
    ): ApiResult<T>()

    data class Error(
        val e: Exception
    ): ApiResult<Nothing>()
}
```

Collecting should look something like this

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    apiService.addProduct(productId,qty,productVariantId)
        .flowOn(defaultDispatcher)
        .catch {
            _addProductList.value= ApiResult.Error(e = it)
        }
        .collect{
            _addProductList.value= ApiResult.Success(data = it)
        }
}
```

and compose

```
when (addProductResult) {
    is ApiResult.Loading -> {
        // Loading state code for products
    }

    is ApiResult.Error -> {
        Log.e("addproductapicall", "failure error: " + addProductResult.e.message)
    }

    is ApiResult.Success -> {
        val Result = addProductResult.data
    }
}
```

If you go with this approach it should work fine.
You will have to work a little, I can't see the entire code.
This should be the correct approach.

Comment: actually , i am getting the response from api successfully, my requirement is to update the text value of clicked item in ProductItem composable after getting api result which is another composable @Faruk Karaca

Comment: you need set `collectAsStateWithLifecycle()`  for `Product` before passing `ProductItem` compose function. If `Product` does not behave like a state, the compose will not understand that it needs to be recompose when its value changes. You need to adapt the following statement into your code.
`var state = viewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()`

`@Composable
fun MyCompose (state: String) { Text(state) }`

Whenever the state here changes, the text will also change.